# Vendor Permission in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to set permissions in Django so that a Vendor can delete or update their own product, not others.

This means if they log in from their account then they can only update or delete their own product, not others.

Comment: How did you model the "ownership" of a product? How are your products en vendors represented in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LoginRequiredMixin in your views class to restrict requests from accessing if the user is not authenticated.

```
  {% if yourfield.owner_id == user.id %}
    (<a href="{% url 'link to update view ' yourfield.id %}">Edit</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'link to delete view' yourfield.id %}">Delete</a>)
    {% endif %}
```

Also use this your html template to only display the updated and delete link if the user is the current logged in user, given that you have a owner field in your model linked to the auth_users table.